# GCP cloud functions vs cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

which service is better in terms of # of concurrent executions, performance and cost GCP Cloud functions or Cloud Run.

I have an API, the expected traffic is 30000 req/second. Now I want to deploy to GCP. which one should i use cloud function or cloud run?

Comment: Recommendations are off-topic on Stack Overflow, but if it supports my use-case I would nowadays go for Cloud Run.

Comment: for 30K request per second, you should go with your own Kubernetes stack on GKE https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine

Comment: If you need to process 30K requests per second, you will have to a) evaluate the limits each service imposes; b) determine how many requests per second your application can handle. There are so many unknowns for your question that there is no answer. Do your own research and then post a question that is on topic for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-vs-cloud-functions-whats-the-lowest-cost-728d59345a2e). Quite old and without all the latest feature of Cloud Run, but in term of concurrency, the basis are the same

In addition, I wrote another [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-performances-with-multiple-cpus-a4c2fccb5192) on the multi CPU usage of Cloud Run. It could be interesting to process concurrently on different instances but also inside the same instance (only possible with Cloud Run, not with Cloud Function that can handle only 1 request at a time per instance).